# How to pass form input value to php function

Tags: php, html, forms, function

I want to write a php page in which there is a html form. I want to send all input (number for example) of my form to a php function (instead of a javascript function; I make this to hide my javascript function code).

How can I send input value to php function?
Is it possible to call the php function through `onclick="function(param1, param2)"`?
I know that javascript is a client-side language while php is server-side.

If it is possible, how can I write the return of the function in an input field?
I want to remain in my page.
Is it correct - `action="#"`?
My code is:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    Inserisci number1: 
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"></input>

    <?php echo "ciaoooo"; ?>

    <br></br>
    Inserisci number2:
    <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"></input>

    <br></br>

    <input type="submit" value="send"></input>
</form>
```

Help me in the implementation of the simple php function and in the passage of values from input to function!
Thanks!

Comment: googled it? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: did you search for ajax ?

Comment: To post to the same page, just use empty action i.e. action="".

Comment: @jimmy You might want to see this page http://w3fools.com/ W3 Schools (unfortunately) is not a reliable source of information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your `action` empty. You don't need to set the  `onclick` attribute, that's only javascript. When you click your submit button, it will reload your page with input from the form. So write your PHP code at the top of the form.

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['submit']) )
{
    //be sure to validate and clean your variables
    $val1 = htmlentities($_GET['val1']);
    $val2 = htmlentities($_GET['val2']);

    //then you can use them in a PHP function. 
    $result = myFunction($val1, $val2);
}
?>

<?php if( isset($result) ) echo $result; //print the result above the form ?>

<form action="" method="get">
    Inserisci number1: 
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"></input>

    <?php echo "ciaoooo"; ?>

    <br></br>
    Inserisci number2:
    <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"></input>

    <br></br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: @jcubic form's can use either - especially POST if they are handling sensitive info like email addresses, D.O.B etc

Comment: @tim.baker I know but he write `method="get"`

Comment: @jcubic I'm confused, what's wrong with him writing GET, your first comment says use GET now you're saying he wrote GET as those he shouldn't have done? Really forms should always use POST as anything in GET *could* be crawled by search engines

Comment: @tim.baker he use get in html form but post in php.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NicholasPickering. Is it correct to make this kind of things to substitute javascript? The method should be "get" or "post"??

Comment: And how can I write the result in a input field in the php page? For example a field after the form. Thanks

Comment: @Gio yes, in this example Javascript is not necessary. You can use either method. "post" is generally considered more secure, and "get" is slightly more convenient.

Comment: @Gio I'm not sure what you mean. See my edit and let me know if that helps you.

Comment: @jcubic I see now, sorry about that!

Comment: @NicholasPickering I think the the line (<?php if( isset($result) ) echo $result; //print the result above the form ?>) is correct. But can I write that result inside an input type="field" putting the value to that result?? If use javascript I can find an element through findElementById so I write the result in the element with that id. I want to know if it is possible with php. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NicholasPickering, why I have the error "undefined variable: result" if i use the variable result in different part of codes??

Comment: @Gio probably because its undefined... make sure its defined by defining it at the top or using `isset`.

Comment: @NicholasPickering In your code you use result in two different part, the fisrt time you define it. The problem is that the second time you use result there is the error. Is the result variable global?

Comment: @NicholasPickering I solved! Thanks a lot! I edit your code, the problem was that the input button did not have the tag name="submit"!

Comment: instead of  $val1 = htmlentities($_GET['val1']); i use
                 $val1 = $_GET['val1']; and it works.

Comment: @GentBerani That's not good! Your script is susceptible to getting hacked now. You need to sanitize user input with htmlentities or via some other means.

Comment: @NicholasPickering can i get help -> bit.ly/2XJVlVd

Comment: This doesn't work if I put the php in a separate file

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty basic, just put in the php file you want to use for processing in the  element.

For example

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
```

Then in process.php you would get the form values using `$_POST['name of the variable]`

Comment: If I do this, I get: Undefined index 'name of the variable '

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into Ajax; [Start here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) this is the best way to stay on the current page and be able to send inputs to php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>
<form action=""> 
First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 

</body>
</html>
```

This gets the users input on the textbox and opens the webpage gethint.php?q=ja from here the php script can do anything with $_GET['q'] and echo back to the page James, Jason....etc

Comment: Think that is far to complex for his needs.

Comment: In his question he says "I want to remain in my page" this to me says Ajax.

Comment: Remain in my page in the sense that after I click on my button the result is visible in an input field in the same php page.

Answer (score 1):

No, the action should be the name of php file. With on click you may only call JavaScript. And please be aware the hiding your code from the user undermines trust. JS runs on the browser so some trust is needed.

Comment: Ok @Christoph but I want to hide some formulas. If I use javascript formulas are visible through web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your php file to the `action` attr of form element.
At the php side you can get the form value by `$_POST['element_name']`.

Answer (score -1):

you must have read about function call . here i give you example of it.

```
<?php
 funtion pr($n)
{
echo $n;
 }
?>
<form action="<?php $f=$_POST['input'];pr($f);?>" method="POST">
<input name=input type=text></input>
</form>
```