# Simple form submit to PHP function failing

Tags: php, forms, function, variables

I'm trying to submit two form field values to a PHP function, on the same page.
The function works perfect manually filling the two values.

```
<?PHP  // Works as expected
echo "<br />"."<br />"."Write text file value: ".sav_newval_of(e, 45);
?>
```

On the form I must be missing something, or I have a syntax error. The web page doesn't fail to display.  I found the below example here: [A 1 Year old Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055115/how-to-pass-form-input-value-to-php-function)

```
    <?php
if( isset($_GET['submit']) ) {
    $val1 = htmlentities($_GET['val1']);
    $val2 = htmlentities($_GET['val2']);

    $result = sav_newval_of($val1, $val2);
}
?>

<?php if( isset($result) ) echo $result; //print the result of the form ?>

<form action="" method="get">
    Input position a-s: 
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"></input>
    <br></br>
    Input quantity value:
    <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"></input>
    <br></br>

    <input type="submit" value="send"></input>
</form>
```

Could it be the placement of my code on the form?
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: And the syntax error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your submit button, or check for something else on your `if(isset($_GET['submit']))` portion:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    Input position a-s: 
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" />
    <br></br>
    Input quantity value:
    <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2" />
    <br></br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

OR keep same form, but change php to:

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['val1']) || isset($_GET['val2'])) {
    $val1 = htmlentities($_GET['val1']);
    $val2 = htmlentities($_GET['val2']);

    $result = sav_newval_of($val1, $val2);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you hidden field as:

```
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='add' >
```

And check on php by using isset function that form has been submitted.